# An error was thrown in afterAll Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'BASE_URL')

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'BASE_URL')

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'BASE_URL')

```
  at Module.553 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/environments/environment.ts:16:71)

  at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)

  at Module.5012 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:4167:74)
```

This is my spec file

```
describe('AdditionalBreaksComponent', () => {

    let component: AdditionalBreaksComponent;

    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AdditionalBreaksComponent>;

    beforeEach(async () => {

        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({

            declarations: [AdditionalBreaksComponent],

            schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],

            providers: [

                {

                    provide: MatDialog,

                    useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('MatDialog', ['open'])

                },

                {

                    provide: ToasterService,

                    useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('ToasterService', ['success', 'error'])

                },

                {

                    provide: PertStaticService,

                    useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('PertStaticService', ['getAllPlants'])

                },

                {

                    provide: AdditionalBreaksService,

                    useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('AdditionalBreaksService', ['getAdditionalBreak', 'deleteAdditionalBreak'])

                },

                {

                    provide: ResourcePoolsService,

                    useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('ResourcePoolsService', ['getResourcePools'])

                },

                {

                    provide: PsStationsService,

                    useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('PsStationsService', ['getPsStations', 'getPsStationById'])

                }

            ]

        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AdditionalBreaksComponent);

        component = fixture.componentInstance;

        fixture.detectChanges();

    });

    it('should create', () => {

        expect(component).toBeTruthy();

    });

}
);
```

And this is my component file

```
        {

            displayName: 'Additional Breaks'

        }

    ];

    constructor(

        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,

        private router: Router,

        private route: ActivatedRoute,

        private dialogService: MatDialog,

        private toasterService: ToasterService,

        private pertStaticService: PertStaticService,

        private additionalBreaksService: AdditionalBreaksService,

        private resourcePoolService: ResourcePoolsService,

        private psStationService: PsStationsService

    ) {

        super();

        this.allowedNullableCustomFunctionColumns = ['psStationId'];

        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({

            search: '',

            plant: this.all

        });

        this.plants = this.pertStaticService.getAllPlants();

    }
```

I tired mocking the services but still got the error. I am not able to identify also what is causing the error?